# Efficient way of extracting names of a large number of variables in R

Tags: r

It could be a very easy question, given that I am very unfamiliar with R. I know normally one can use `deparse(substitute(.))` to extract the name of a variable.  However, if I have a long list of variables (let's say it's built without names), how can I extract the name of each variable efficiently? I was thinking about using loops, but the `deparse(substitute(.))` method would obviously generate the 'general' variable name we used to denote every item.

Sample code:

```
countries<-
list(austria,belgium,czech,denmark,france,germany,italy,luxemberg,netherlands,poland,swiss)
```

Suppose I want to get `countryNames` equals to `list("austria","belgium",...,"swiss")`, how shall I code?  I tried generating the list using `countries <- list(countryA = countryA, countryB = countryB, ...)`, but it was extremely tedious, and in some cases I might only have an unnamed input list from elsewhere.

Comment: I don't know if you are looking for `names(countries)`. Unquoted, are `austria`, etc objects' names?

Comment: Yes, I believe they're objects.. Maybe each of them contains, for example, the population in each of these countries, and he wants their names, too.

Comment: Exactly.  They are objects.  I've edited the question so it looks clearer now.  Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`countries` would just have values of each individual objects (`austria`,`belgium` etc.). To access the names you need to create a named list while creating `countries` which can be done like :

```
countries <- list(austria = austria,belgium = belgium....)
```

However, if this is very tedious you can use `tibble::lst` which creates the names automatically without explicitly mentioning them.

```
countries <- tibble::lst(austria,belgium....)
```

In both the case you can access the names using `names(countries)`.

Comment: Thanks!  I was exactly using the first method, which was notoriously tedious for a larger dataset.  That `lst()` from `tibble` is great!

Comment: By the way, is it otherwise possible to use a loop to "extract" the names?

Comment: Why do you need loop to extract the names when you can do this via `names` directly?

Answer (score 0):

If the country objects are the only ones loaded in the global environment, we can do this easily with `ls` and `mget` to return a named `list` of values

```
countries <- mget(ls())
```

Comment: This is a clever idea!  Thanks!